# Redirect once on first visit

Tags: redirect

I would like to find a way to have visitors who visit my site every 24 hours to be redirected to a different page where they click a link that takes them back to the main page.

I've found a few ways to almost accomplish this but every time they land on the homepage it keeps redirecting them back to the other page.

I've looked at a large number of plugins but I have yet to find anything.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have worked till now for better understanding of where you are?

Comment: I don't have any code for this, I was using plugins and the code I had used I've since removed.